# Laravel 4.2: (Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost') error

Tags: php, laravel-4, homestead

I get the following error message in the terminal when I try to execute `php artisan migrate` command

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I don't use `homestead`. I have these 2 files in the root directory: `.env.php` and `.env.local.php` in which I keep sensitive values and values that differ between environments (development and production). So what's wrong and how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Type `hostname` in your terminal and hit Enter key. This will let you know your hostname (Name of your computer/machine).
2. In `bootstrap/start.php` file, use this line `'local' => array('put-your-hostname-here'),` instead of this line `'local' => array('homestead'),`
3. In `.env.local.php` file, save your local database configuration like this:

   ```
   <?php

   return array(

       "DB_NAME"     => "local_database_name",
       "DB_USERNAME" => "local_database_username",
       "DB_PASSWORD" => "local_database_password",

       // any other configuration..

   );
   ```
4. In `.env.php` file, save your remote database configuration like this:

   ```
   <?php

   return array(

       "DB_NAME"     => "remote_database_name",
       "DB_USERNAME" => "remote_database_username",
       "DB_PASSWORD" => "remote_database_password",

       // any other configuration..

   );
   ```
5. In `app/config/database.php` file, set your database connection like this:

   ```
   'mysql' => array(
       'driver'    => 'mysql',
       'host'      => 'localhost',

       'database'  => $_ENV['DB_NAME'],
       'username'  => $_ENV['DB_USERNAME'],
       'password'  => $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'],

       'charset'   => 'utf8',
       'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
       'prefix'    => '',
   ),
   ```
6. Finally, you MUST remove or disable any working code exists in `app/config/local/database.php` file, otherwise the error you mentioned will be thrown.